# How can i apply css to a pareticular contact form 7?

Tags: wordpress

I am using contact form 7 and made 5 forms from it and now i want to apply css to a particular form. Please help. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify the names of the specific id's and div's in the contact form you want to manipulate and do the same in the css

e.g.

```
#contactFormIChanged {
list-style:none;
margin:0;
}
#contactFormIChanged li{
float: left;
    height: 60px;
    margin:0 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 540px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the page where there's the form and look that classes and IDs have been assigned to that form. Then style your form using these classes/IDs.